# Is there any way to hide salesforce standard file size validation

Tags: error-messages

I want to hide the below salesforce file size standard validation and show custom error validation. How can we do it.

[image]

Regards

Comment: That looks like a VF page. YOu can show whatever error you want.

Comment: this is a standard message of slaesforce which i dont want to show if the file size is more than 25 mb. How can i hide this message

Comment: This is standard, if you want to change the behavior you should extend the controller or create a custom controller. Then you can use ErrorMessages as you wish.